# How do I use internal storage in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: security, xamarin.forms, storage

I want to store text files with contact information in my app, and I want that information to be stored securely. The Android developers' website says I can store sensitive data in internal storage, but that's for an Android app and I'm using Xamarin.Forms to make my app for Android and iOS. How do I store something in internal storage on Xamarin.Forms and should I do something different for the iOS version?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=ios

Comment: @Jason That's designed for small pieces of information like passwords. I need something that will work for entire text files, but thank you.

Comment: after looking at the Android docs, "internal storage" is just the term they use for normal file storage in the app folders.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#application-directories